# How to access SVG elements with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm messing around with SVG and I was hoping I could create SVG files in Illustrator and access elements with JavaScript.

Here's the SVG file Illustrator kicks out (it also seems to add a load of junk to the beginning of the file that I've removed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="276.843px" height="233.242px" viewBox="0 0 276.843 233.242" enable-background="new 0 0 276.843 233.242"
     xml:space="preserve">
<path id="delta" fill="#231F20" d="M34.074,86.094L0,185.354l44.444,38.519l80.741-0.74l29.63-25.186l-26.667-37.037
    c0,0-34.815-5.926-37.778-6.667s-13.333-28.889-13.333-28.889l7.407-18.519l31.111-2.963l5.926-21.481l-12.593-38.519l-43.704-5.185
    L34.074,86.094z"/>
<path id="cargo" fill="#DFB800" d="M68.148,32.761l43.704,4.445l14.815,42.963l-7.407,26.667l-33.333,2.963l-4.444,14.074
    l54.074-1.481l22.222,36.296l25.926-3.704l25.926-54.074c0,0-19.259-47.408-21.481-47.408s-31.852-0.741-31.852-0.741
    l-19.259-39.259L92.593,8.316L68.148,32.761z"/>
<polygon id="beta" fill="#35FF1F" points="86.722,128.316 134.593,124.613 158.296,163.872 190.889,155.724 214.593,100.909 
    194.593,52.02 227.186,49.057 246.444,92.02 238.297,140.909 216.074,172.761 197.556,188.316 179.778,169.798 164.963,174.983 
    163.481,197.946 156.815,197.946 134.593,159.428 94.593,151.279 "/>
<path class="monkey" id="alpha" fill="#FD00FF" d="M96.315,4.354l42.963,5.185l18.519,42.222l71.852-8.148l20.74,46.667l-5.926,52.593
    l-24.444,34.074l-25.185,15.555l-14.074-19.259l-8.889,2.964l-1.481,22.222l-14.074,2.963l-25.186,22.963l-74.074,4.444
    l101.481,4.444c0,0,96.297-17.777,109.63-71.852S282.24,53.983,250.389,20.65S96.315,4.354,96.315,4.354z"/>
</svg>
```

As you can probably see, each element has an ID, and I was hoping to be able to access individual elements with JavaScript so I could change the `fill` attribute and respond to events such as clicks.

The HTML is bog basic:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG Illustrator Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <object data="alpha.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="alphasvg" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

I guess this is two questions really:

1. Is it possible to do it this way, as opposed to using something like Raphaël or jQuery SVG?
2. If it is possible, what's the technique?

---

**UPDATE**

At the moment, I've resorted to using Illustrator to create the SVG file, and I'm using [Raphaël JS](https://dmitrybaranovskiy.github.io/raphael/) to create paths and simply copying the point data from the SVG file and pasting it into the `path()` function. Creating complex paths such as might be needed for a map, by coding the point data manually is (to my knowledge) prohibitively complex.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

> Is it possible to do it this way, as opposed to using something like Raphael or jQuery SVG?

Definitely.

> If it is possible, what's the technique?

This annotated code snippet works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SVG Illustrator Test</title> 
    </head>
    <body>

        <object data="alpha.svg" type="image/svg+xml"
         id="alphasvg" width="100%" height="100%"></object>

        <script>
            var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");

            // It's important to add an load event listener to the object,
            // as it will load the svg doc asynchronously
            a.addEventListener("load",function(){

                // get the inner DOM of alpha.svg
                var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
                // get the inner element by id
                var delta = svgDoc.getElementById("delta");
                // add behaviour
                delta.addEventListener("mousedown",function(){
                        alert('hello world!')
                }, false);
            }, false);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note that a limitation of this technique is that it is restricted by the same-origin policy, so `alpha.svg` must be hosted on the same domain as the `.html` file, otherwise the inner DOM of the object will be inaccessible.

**Important thing** to run this HTML, you need host HTML file to web server like IIS, Tomcat

Comment: a note on @jbeard4 's note: in some browsers this same-origin policy results in the need to use a server (even if you code is only using html and js [serverside]) the access policy will prevent access to the svg.

Comment: Important thing to run this HTML, you need host HTML file to web server like IIS, Tomcat

Comment: As @HienNguyen mentioned, before running it on a web server, It did not work. The value returned for `document.getElementById("alphasvg").contentDocument` was `null`.

Comment: TL;DR: [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/contentDocument) bridges from the HTML context to the SVG context

Answer (score 24):

In case you use jQuery you need to wait for `$(window).load`, because the embedded SVG document might not be yet loaded at `$(document).ready`

```
$(window).load(function () {

    //alert("Document loaded, including graphics and embedded documents (like SVG)");
    var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");

    //get the inner DOM of alpha.svg
    var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;

    //get the inner element by id
    var delta = svgDoc.getElementById("delta");
    delta.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){ alert('hello world!')}, false);
});
```

Comment: While using this code, this other answer might be a useful complement: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5990945/1515819

Comment: in case of jQuery you'd better use `$('#alphasvg').load` instead of `$(window).load`. This will allow you to change attribute `data` on the fly

Comment: Note that while you can use jQuery to access elements within svg, you cannot use it to append elements to an svg.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642035/jquerys-append-not-working-with-svg-element for why.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using an `<img>` tag for the SVG, then you cannot manipulate its contents (as far as I know).

As the accepted answer shows, using `<object>` is an option.

I needed this recently and used `gulp-inject` during my gulp build to inject the contents of an SVG file directly into the HTML document as an `<svg>` element, which is then very easy to work with using CSS selectors and `querySelector`/`getElementBy*`.

Comment: `img` tag is useful to big SVG load... To use complex (and interactive!) SVG  the better to use [D3js](https://d3js.org/), that is like a lite jQuery, specialized in  SVG+DOM+data manipulation.