# Dynamically change the CSS file of an external SVG file?

Tags: javascript, css, xml, svg, stylesheet

**How to tell to the SVG image to use another CSS file ?**

- A web page displays a SVG file.
- A button allows to switch between classic colors to high contrast on the whole web page including the SVG image.

### Attempt

**`w.css`**  (white background)

```css
svg { background-color:white; }
path{ fill:none; stroke:black; stroke-width:8px; }
```

**`b.css`** (black background)

```css
svg { background-color:black; }
path{ fill:none; stroke:white; stroke-width:10px; }
```

**`image.svg`**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="w.css" title="classic" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="b.css" title="contrast" alternate="yes" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
   <path d="M150,100 H50 V300 H150 M250,300 H300" />
</svg>
```

**`example.html`**

```html
<html>
<body>

<embed id="svg_image" src="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
var embed = document.getElementById("svg_image");
function change_css(file){
    var svgdoc = embed.getSVGDocument();
    var b = svgdoc.childNodes;
    for (var i=0; i<b.length; i++){
        var itm = b.item(i);
        itm.Data = "href='"+ file +"' type='text/css'" ;
    }
}
</script>

<input name="c" type="radio" onclick="change_css('b.css');">High contrast<br>
<input name="c" type="radio" onclick="change_css('w.css');" checked="yes">Classic

</body>
</html>
```

**WEB SEARCH:** No answer found in 2011
http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/svg-developers/message/56679

**UPDATE:** See also [question about correctly structuring javascript, css, and svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569789/question-about-correctly-structuring-javascript-css-and-svg)
Maybe jQuery SVG (keith-wood.name)...

Comment: I'm not sure what's the question here. Your approach is good, except the `data` attribute of processing instruction node should be lowercase. You also don't need two `<?xml-stylesheet ?>` PIs, creating just one and manipulating its `data` is enough.

Comment: Yes, duri, you are right: I have lowercased `itm.Data` => `itm.data` and it works :-)

Comment: PS: firebug v1.8.2 do not detect this bug :-( `   ` => bug report

Comment: @duri : For bug report, I need to know whether firebug has to lowercase `Data` or firebug has to detect mistake in attribute case.

Comment: This is not a bug. A node is an object so you're allowed to set any property, whether it has special function or not. Using `itm.Data` is the same as `itm.someOtherCustomProperty` - nothing will change if you set it, but you can do so. Javascript is case sensitive so `data` and `Data` properties are two unrelated things.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not the best idea to switch actual stylesheets. You're probably better off if you set a CSS class on a very high level and then switching that class with Javascript. Then you can put all the CSS rules in one file and just have to use selectors like (simplified):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="someclass">
    <style>
        .someclass .mypath { stroke: blue; }
        .someotherclass .mypath { stroke: red; }
    </style>
    <path d="M150,100 H50 V300 H150 M250,300 H300" class="mypath" />
</svg>
```

You know what I mean? It's like an if...else construct. If it's a descendant of `someclass` make it blue, otherwise make it red.

That said, I've heard that some browsers have problems with external stylesheets in SVG documents.

Comment: Please @DanMan explain how to switch from one class to another. Do you mean to parse all the elements and change each style attribute?

Comment: Hi @DanMan. Do you mean `element.className = (element.className === 'someclass' ? 'someotherclass' : 'someclass');` ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3319/css-background-color-in-javascript/16037#16037

Comment: Pretty much like that, yes. I've expanded my example.

Comment: Relying on JavaScript to implement accessibility sounds like a bad, bad idea.

Comment: He described the target group as visually impaired, not blind. So i see no problem here. If they were completely blind, what good would changed colors do? Otherwise he'd have to store 2 versions of each map on the server and then provide links to them.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.thesitewizard.com/javascripts/change-style-sheets.shtml happens to claim to explain how to enable/disable style sheets from javascript.  Perhaps you can adapt it to SVG.

I did a quick experiment using firebug against a web page that embedded an SVG that contained a reference to an external CSS.

```
o=document.getElementsByTagName("object")
svg = o[0].getSVGDocument()
svg.styleSheets[0].disabled = true
```

It appears to work.

Comment: Here's a demo: http://svg-wow.org/alternate-stylesheet/alternate-stylesheet.xhtml (it's XHTML with svg inline).