# access SVG elements via Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

This is a follow up to a question asked before at: [How to access SVG elements with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript)
However, the solution does not seem to work for me. I am testing on the latest version of Chrome. I have a map of the US as an SVG file, which I have downloaded on my machine and made some changes to the xml code.

I have the svg embedded using the object tag and assigned an id of "USAsvg" and am proceeding with baby-steps first. For a button onclick event I am executing the following code without success. Here 'CA' is a state declared using the path tag within the svg file.

```
var a = document.getElementById('USAsvg');
var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; 
var delta = svgDoc.getElementById('CA');

alert(delta.value);
```

Comment: Have you seen this? :
http://www.carto.net/papers/svg/manipulating_svg_with_dom_ecmascript/

Comment: You should describe in more detail what isn't working. Are you seeing any `alert` at all? What's it contain? Any errors in the JavaScript console? Chrome comes with a rich set of development tools, including a console and a debugger, so you don't have to use `alert()` - are you using that already? If not, you **really should.**

Comment: I have, I am trying to access the SVG elements from outside the file upon embedding. If my current approach proves unsuccessful, I might have to use this approach.

Comment: Other useful resources: [Mozilla Dev Center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is an excellent source of all things JavaScript. See: [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SVG), [SVG in HTML Introduction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/svg_in_html_introduction), and [Inter-document scripting: referencing embedded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Scripting#Inter-document_scripting.3a_referencing_embedded_SVG).

Comment: Matt, I used your suggestions and tried debugging the javascript under Chrome Developer tools. Seems like the contentDocument itself is "undefined". thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

this works in the latest chrome,
load the SVG into your DOM directly, then manipulate it as if it were a normal html node,
the html() function in jQuery does not work, use text() instead.

```
$('.your_div_for_svg').load('svg/file.svg', function(){
      $('#some_textnode_w_id_within_svg').text('Hello word');
});
```