# editing svg graphics loaded from external source

Tags: javascript, svg, google-api

Is it possible to affect svg graphics loaded from (for example) [google code (charts, etc.)](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#gauge) ? What I need to be able to do is change display styles ( font size and / or color, etc.)

Am I out of luck on that since  all the graphical elements reside in an iframe?

If so, any recommendations on jQuery/js lib for creating pie charts, etc? From what I've seen raphael.js looks very interesting.

Just wonder what the proper approach wold be in this case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eric Dahlstrom wrote an example showing how to do this as part of an answer to a similar question previously: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend you check out d3: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/

Comment: ... holly smokes! That's some nice stuff.

Comment: Yeah its the way of the future. I recently used it to make some graphs, and it was awesome.