# Reusability embedding svg into html

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm struggling a little bit to figure out a proper way how to reuse *.svg files by placing them at different places within my HTML site, but applying different style sheets without using JavaScript.

Snippet from index.html:

```
<OBJECT type="image/svg+xml" data="myLogo.svg" class="svglogo">
<img src="svglogo_fallback.png">
</OBJECT>
```

myLogo.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" class="mySvg" id="test" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="841.89px" height="595.28px" viewBox="0 0 841.89 595.28" enable-background="new 0 0 841.89 595.28" xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
    <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
       .mySvg .teste {
         fill: red;
       }
    ]]></style>
  </defs>

<path class="teste" fill="#000000" d="abcdefg"/>
</svg>
```

One possibility as seen in the *.svg is to use CSS to change the fill to red, this works quite well, but also means that every embedded myLogo.svg will turn out red.

Is there any way how to assign proper CSS styles to the embedded object without using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but I'm pretty sure the answer is that you can't do things the way you want. I think this question is relevant: [How to apply a style to an embedded SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg)