# Making an SVG file with a custom font viewable to a user who doesn't have the font installed

Tags: c#, javascript, xml, svg

I've implemented a customized version of [svg-edit](https://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/) with [svg-font-loader](https://github.com/clintberry/svg-font-loader) on top of it. When the user is editing an SVG file, the custom fonts work well thanks to svg-font-loader (I simply pre-load the necessary custom font on the editor before loading the SVG string).

Once the user has finished with editing, I save the new SVG string to the file system (using `XDocument's` `Parse()` and `Save()`.

I then need to display this SVG file to the user inside an `<img>` tag, but the fonts don't work unless the user installs them on their machine.

How can I encode the SVG string (Base64 or?) before saving to the file system, so that it displays correctly? Would I need to parse the SVG string and only encode certain parts? Is there a tool I can use?

**edit:** Alternatively, if I install the fonts on the server, is there a way to serialize the SVG to PNG on the server-side, and then display this? Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using webfonts in the svg. When you save the svg just write out an @font-face stylerule with the custom font base64-encoded.

Here's an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/fonts/webfont-datauri.svg).

Comment: Wow this looks promising. I'm quite new to this - do I manually parse the SVG string and insert <style>...</style> with the encoded font reference? Then do I manually add a reference to the CSS class? The string looks like this: "...<text xml:space="preserve" text-anchor="left" font-family="Wagnasty" font-size="24" id="svg_2" y="176" x="208" stroke-width="0" stroke="#000000" fill="#ffffff">Test</text>..."

Comment: Busy reading your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg/4906603#4906603 and it's starting to make sense..

Comment: In case you feel like helping: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12874102/how-to-use-a-base64-encoded-font-in-an-svg-file