# How to change embedded SVG file fill color on hover with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, user-interface, svg, hover

I've got a big  element, that includes SVG embed element (external file). I'd like to change its fill colour on a:hover. How would you approach it? It really drives me crazy :)

What I thought should work is:

```
$("a#title").hover(function() {
$("svg#logo").attr('fill','#f0f');
});
```

Comment: Wait, so you want to change the color used in the svg file with jquery?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this specifically, but it looks like this guy has a jquery plugin you could use located [here.](http://keith-wood.name/svg.html)

Comment: No, I'm not trying to use CSS, I'm trying to change an 'attribute' (fill). I believe these are different.

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is ok for when the svg is inline in the html. However when it's embedded by reference (embed, object, iframe, img) then the svg is actually a separate document. You can think of this as trying to change attributes in an html document that was referenced by an iframe.

Is the link inside the svg? If so you can put the styles/scripts inside the svg.

Here's [an example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html) that changes the fill of an svg shape from the html document (embed, object, iframe).

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately the link <a> is in html, so not inside svg.

Comment: As I wrote above that will only work when the svg is inline, not when it's referenced.