# How do I fill/stroke an SVG file on my website?

Tags: svg, fill, stroke

I Googled this issue for about 30 minutes and was surprised nobody has asked so maybe it's not possible.

I'm using this line to embed the SVG file that I made in AI (note that when I saved the SVG, I had no fill OR stroke on the paths):

`<object type="image/svg+xml" data="example.svg" height=600px width=600px>Your browser does not support SVG</object>`

This obviously comes up with no image because the SVG file has no fill or stroke.
I tried adding in

`...fill=yellow>`

or

`...style="fill:yellow;">`

but I'm not having any luck.  Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to apply a style to an embedded SVG?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg)

Answer (score 1):

Have a nice trick: Embed it as `<img>` and use javascript to convert it into inline `<svg>` with this code (that came from SO I think). Now you can manipulate this SVG object

**CODE:**:

`/*
        * Replace all SVG images with inline SVG
        */
        jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
            var $img = jQuery(this);
            var imgID = $img.attr('id');
            var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
            var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

            jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
                // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
                var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

                // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
                }
                // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
                }

                // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
                $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

                // Replace image with new SVG
                $img.replaceWith($svg);
            });

        });`

Comment: Sidenote: SVG image can be manipulated when inserted as <object>, <embed> or <iframe>. Just that cross-origin resource sharing issue creeps up from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to add the fill or style on the object element? If so, that's not going to work. Those [properties are not supported on the object element](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.3). You're going to have to add it into the SVG in the SVG file.