# Load a new SVG on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Been lurking and searching on the site for years, but I have come across an issue I can't seem to figure out.

I am creating a (very simple) coloring book for my daughter.  I have been able to nail down coloring a single picture (SVG).  I am trying to give her multiple pictures to color.  What would be the best method to load a new SVG, path and all,  within a div when she click an image below the main canvas? I have put the SVG code inline and have called it by using PHP.  Both seem to work for the initial page load but I can't get the secondary load to work.

Here is my attempt -  https://jsfiddle.net/shockey8oz/LL9048kg/

```
$('.thumb').click(function() {
   var choice = $(this).attr('id');
   $('.canvas').load('http://www.shockeyfamily.org/final/' + choice + '.svg');
});
```

Thanks,
Shockey8oz

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.thumb').click(function() {
  var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
var can = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    $('.canvas').html(can.innerHTML);
}
   var choice = $(this).attr('id');
img.src ='http://www.shockeyfamily.org/final/' + choice + '.svg';

});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  However, the 'canvas' element shows blank when I click on an image.  Is an ajax to php script a viable solution?

Answer (score 0):

First, test out the solution found here: [Best practice for using SVG images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002310/best-practice-for-using-svg-images/25032941#25032941)

Update code to toggle between two different shapes. If images is stored on another server, then you'd have to read up on [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) and reconfig the image server's `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` setting.

Alternative solution is to use inline method: [How do I fill/stroke an SVG file on my website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697299/how-do-i-fill-stroke-an-svg-file-on-my-website/16708234#16708234)