# Modify SVG from external source

Tags: jquery, wordpress, svg

I tried to add in many ways an SVG inlive in wordpress but it doesn't work probably because of the syntax when I copied the code inside ( [HERE if you want to know of what I'm talking about)](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/svg-inline-doesnt-work?replies=7#post-4956234)

So I need to insert it from an external source ([SVG file](http://studiodentisticocova.com/img/dentisuperiori.svg)) BUT I tried to modify it (only change  fill color) with CSS (every path has his proper ID) and nothing works.

Is there a way to do that in jQuery?
Is there a way to modify it in the DOM?

Comment: Have you ever tried the jquery svg library http://keith-wood.name/svg.html here.
Dont forget to check SVG DOM tab there and samples. I think this library works for you.

Comment: Seems like you can. See this: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/get-embedded-svg-document-script.html

Answer (score 1):

YOu could change the color by using method "attr" in jquery. and set the color attribute for SVG object.

**Example in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x01z479q/)**

Here is the link about [attr() in Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)!

Here is the example code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test(){
    $('#id rect').attr("fill", "yellow");
    }
</script>
<button onclick="test()"> test</button>
 <svg id="id" width="125" height="65"><rect x="3" y="3" rx="20" ry="20"  width="120" height="60" fill="red" ></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are embedding your svg file via `<object>` tag you can use an external stylesheet inside the `<svg>` file

e.g in your `html` file you should use

```
<object data="svg-file.svg"></object>
```

and in your svg file use

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="yourstylesheet.css" ?>   
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
...
</svg>
```

to link an external stylesheet to your svg file.
If you also want to use a script for manipulating your `svg` file I recommend using ecmascript. It should look something like this:

```
<svg>
....
  <script type="text/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
  //some script code here
 ]]></script>
...
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use CSS to alter the properties of an embedded SVG (ie via `<img>`, `<object>` etc).
Styles don't apply across document boundaries.

However if you embed via an `<object>` you can use the DOM to add CSS to the SVG itself.

[How to apply a style to an embedded SVG?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg)