# Why changing using JS, attributes of embedded svg with external css, fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have a svg image I created with Inkscape.
Image has an external css file, so it is possible to changes some of the image colors and other svg properties.
This works OK.
Foe example, changing `stroke: red` in the css file to yellow, will make the image with yellow frame (aka stroke).

I'm also trying to modify the colors with js.
Im using jQuery for that. but this doesn't have any effect.

Question is why css works and js isnt?

```js
function changeColor(fillColor,strokeColor){
               console.log("changeColor",fillColor,strokeColor);

        let id = "#rect983";

        let el = $(id);
        if(fillColor){
          el.attr("fill", fillColor);
        }
        if(strokeColor){el.attr("stroke", strokeColor);}
    }
```

```css
#rect983 { 
    fill:#50574f; 
    stroke:red;
    /*fill:#000000;*/
    /* stroke:#000000; */
    stroke-opacity:1;
    stroke-width:3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="logo.css"?> 

<svg
   width="40px"
   height="40px"
   viewBox="0 0 79.374999 79.374999"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg10099"
   inkscape:version="1.1 (c68e22c387, 2021-05-23)"
   sodipodi:docname="base2.svg"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="namedview10101"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     showgrid="true"
     inkscape:zoom="2.6934743"
     inkscape:cx="182.29244"
     inkscape:cy="135.69834"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1017"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer2"
     inkscape:snap-bbox="true"
     inkscape:snap-intersection-paths="true"
     inkscape:object-paths="true"
     inkscape:snap-smooth-nodes="true"
     inkscape:snap-page="true"
     inkscape:bbox-paths="true"
     inkscape:bbox-nodes="true"
     units="px"
     width="300px">
    <inkscape:grid
       type="xygrid"
       id="grid14659"
       spacingx="2.6458333"
       spacingy="2.6458333" />
  </sodipodi:namedview>
  <defs
     id="defs10096">
    <inkscape:path-effect
       effect="fillet_chamfer"
       id="path-effect8790"
       is_visible="true"
       lpeversion="1"
       satellites_param="F,0,1,1,0,39.148651,0,1 @ F,0,0,1,0,39.148651,0,1 @ F,0,1,1,0,39.148651,0,1 @ F,0,1,1,0,39.148651,0,1"
       unit="px"
       method="auto"
       mode="F"
       radius="0"
       chamfer_steps="1"
       flexible="false"
       use_knot_distance="true"
       apply_no_radius="true"
       apply_with_radius="true"
       only_selected="false"
       hide_knots="false" />
    <linearGradient
       id="linearGradient14259"
       inkscape:swatch="solid">
      <stop
         style="stop-color:#1f5615;stop-opacity:0.33725491;"
         offset="0"
         id="stop14257" />
    </linearGradient>
    <meshgradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       id="meshgradient1073"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       x="161.65112"
       y="20.370331">
      <meshrow
         id="meshrow1075">
        <meshpatch
           id="meshpatch1077">
          <stop
             path="c 59.9628,0  119.926,0  179.889,0"
             style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1"
             id="stop1079" />
          <stop
             path="c 0,66.8409  0,133.682  0,200.523"
             style="stop-color:#50574f;stop-opacity:1"
             id="stop1081" />
          <stop
             path="c -59.9629,0  -119.926,0  -179.889,0"
             style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1"
             id="stop1083" />
          <stop
             path="c 0,-66.8409  0,-133.682  0,-200.523"
             style="stop-color:#50574f;stop-opacity:1"
             id="stop1085" />
        </meshpatch>
      </meshrow>
    </meshgradient>
    <meshgradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       id="meshgradient3117"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       x="31.496464"
       y="23.677107">
      <meshrow
         id="meshrow3119">
        <meshpatch
           id="meshpatch3121">
          <stop
             path="c 45.0603,0  90.1206,0  135.181,0"
             style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1"
             id="stop3123" />
          <stop
             path="c 0,65.7387  0,131.477  0,197.216"
             style="stop-color:#50574f;stop-opacity:1"
             id="stop3125" />
          <stop
             path="c -45.0603,0  -90.1206,0  -135.181,0"
             style="stop-color:#ffffff;stop-opacity:1"
             id="stop3127" />
          <stop
             path="c 0,-65.7387  0,-131.477  0,-197.216"
             style="stop-color:#50574f;stop-opacity:1"
             id="stop3129" />
        </meshpatch>
      </meshrow>
    </meshgradient>
  </defs>
  <g
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer2"
     inkscape:label="background">
    <rect
       style="stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:0;stroke-dasharray:none;paint-order:fill markers stroke"
       id="rect983"
       width="76.43"
       height="76.430145"
       x="1.5"
       y="1.5"
       ry="6.4650736" />
  </g>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <g
       aria-label="FA"
       transform="matrix(0.22470239,0,0,0.3430025,-2.2235368,-1.6895186)"
       id="text13011"
       style="font-size:270.891px;line-height:1.25;font-family:'Arial Rounded MT Bold';-inkscape-font-specification:'Arial Rounded MT Bold, Normal';letter-spacing:0px;opacity:1;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#020000">
      <path
         d="M 148.15948,53.967163 H 70.780947 v 49.601627 h 64.680513 q 8.99443,0 13.35937,4.1004 4.49722,3.96813 4.49722,10.71395 0,6.74582 -4.49722,10.71395 -4.49721,3.96813 -13.35937,3.96813 H 70.780947 v 63.88689 q 0,12.16893 -5.555381,18.12112 -5.423111,5.81992 -14.020726,5.81992 -8.729885,0 -14.285267,-5.95219 -5.42311,-5.95219 -5.42311,-17.98885 V 47.750427 q 0,-8.465344 2.513149,-13.756184 2.513148,-5.42311 7.803988,-7.803988 5.423111,-2.513149 13.756183,-2.513149 h 92.589697 q 9.39124,0 13.88845,4.232672 4.62949,4.100401 4.62949,10.846221 0,6.878092 -4.62949,11.110763 -4.49721,4.100401 -13.88845,4.100401 z"
         id="path2635"
         style="fill:url(#meshgradient3117);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
         sodipodi:insensitive="true" />
      <path
         d="m 299.60978,195.6294 -9.25897,-24.33787 h -78.83352 l -9.25896,24.86695 q -5.42312,14.54981 -9.25897,19.70838 -3.83586,5.02629 -12.56575,5.02629 -7.40717,0 -13.09483,-5.42311 -5.68765,-5.42311 -5.68765,-12.3012 0,-3.96813 1.32271,-8.2008 1.32271,-4.23267 4.36494,-11.77212 L 216.94041,57.273938 q 2.11633,-5.423111 5.02629,-12.962557 3.04224,-7.671718 6.34901,-12.698015 3.43905,-5.026298 8.86216,-8.068531 5.55538,-3.174504 13.62391,-3.174504 8.2008,0 13.62391,3.174504 5.55538,3.042233 8.86216,7.93626 3.43904,4.894026 5.68765,10.581679 2.38088,5.555382 5.9522,14.946622 l 50.65979,125.128354 q 5.95219,14.28527 5.95219,20.76655 0,6.74582 -5.68765,12.43347 -5.55538,5.55538 -13.49164,5.55538 -4.62949,0 -7.93626,-1.71952 -3.30678,-1.58725 -5.55539,-4.36494 -2.2486,-2.90996 -4.89402,-8.72989 -2.51315,-5.95219 -4.36494,-10.4494 z m -77.77535,-53.8343 h 57.9347 L 250.53724,61.771152 Z"
         id="path2637"
         style="fill:url(#meshgradient1073);fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:4;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none"
         sodipodi:insensitive="true" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
    <button onclick="changeColor('yellow','black')">change colors</button>
```

Comment: jQuery does not play nice with SVG unless you actually *have* the `jquery-svg` plugin that you tagged. Your code certainly doesn't. You don't need jQuery for this anyway, just `document.getElementById('rect983').setAttribute("fill", fillColor)` will do fine.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it doesn't work either. Isn't jQuery only wrapper to basic dom operations, such as your solution offers?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol "..unless you actually have the jquery-svg plugin that you tagged" What do you mean by tagged? what do you mean by "actually have"? and why do you call it `jquery-svg` plugin?

Comment: jQuery is designed to work with HTML in a fully cross-browser compatible manner. SVG is an entirely different language and is not cross-browser compatible (older browsers don't support it). The fact that both of them happen to have similar interfaces is simply because both are derivatives of the same base language. [tag:jquery-svg], which you tagged in your question, is a separate plug-in for jQuery that enables support for SVG's differences.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol wrong tag. fied. I actually used jQuery due to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20402344/modify-svg-from-external-source) (and others) suggesting jQuery is the way. anyway, still not working.

Comment: jquery is able to handle SVG attributes for years now... The problem is simply that presentationnal attributes have lower priority than their CSS equivalents. Either set the CSS property through your JS (`el.css("fill", ...`), either set the original colors through the attributes (`fill="#50574f"`) rather than through CSS.