# How to Change Stroke Color in SVG Image on Hover Event?

Tags: javascript, svg, hover

I've been searching through the site for an answer, and it seems no one has really received a definitive answer for this specific question.

I'm looking to change the color of the stroke on an SVG icon that I made when it is hovered over.

Here is my current code:

```
<object data="price.svg" type="image/svg+xml" class="icon">
    <a href="price.svg" />
</object>
```

CSS:

```css
.icon {width:100%}
```

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg ?

Comment: It's easy if you can *embed* the SVG in the HTML file. Then you could reference the `#Layer_1` ID and change the style of the child elements.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I managed to get it figured out! http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fDuKi @helderdarocha, if you set your response as an answer, I will mark it as correct! Thanks again!

Comment: I can do that, but please edit your question including the code of the problem you were asking about (the codepen link is not enough) so it can be a reference for others who might have a similar problem (and also avoid its deletion).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't change the properties of a foreign object that way. But it's easy if you can *embed* the SVG in the HTML file. Then you could reference the IDs of your SVG and change the style of the child elements.

Replace

```
<object data="price.svg" ...> ... </object>
```

with the contents of your SVG file:

```
<svg ...><path id="styled-element" ...></svg>
```

Now you can apply a style to it:

```
#styled-element:hover { stroke:red }
```