# How to change the Fill color of an SVG path via CSS

Tags: css, svg

I know that we can change the `fill` color of an SVG path using CSS if/when the raw SVG is added to the HTML page.

However, I don't know if it is possible to change the `fill` color if the SVG is referenced within an `<img>` tag. - Is it possible? If so, how?

Example: This `fill` example doesn't work because I am referencing the svg within an `img` tag.

```
<html>
    ...
    <style>
        #foo{
           fill: #ccc;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <img id="foo" src="myicon.svg" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't impact via CSS  on SVG Image that is source is in another file. 
yo can impact only in the file itself or to put the SVG inline in the HTML and than the styles will wokrs.

SVG Inline Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
  #foo{
    fill: #ccc;
  }
</style>

<svg id="foo" width="300" height="200">
  <polygon points="100,10 40,180 190,60 10,60 160,180"
  style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```