# Update stroke color css

Tags: css, svg

I've got a svg

tick.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200"><circle cx="150" cy="150" r="40" stroke="#000" fill="none" stroke-width="6" class="tickCol" stroke-linecap="round></svg>
```

And I use it as

```
#checkBox{
    background: url('tick.svg') 50% 50% no-repeat #000;
}
```

I need to change the stroke color using css. I tried the below but no luck. How do I change the `stroke` color in css?

```
.tickCol{
  stroke: #f60;
}
```

Comment: Did you put the CSS in the SVG file? If not, that's your problem.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks for your reply. Yes the url path is fine.

Comment: What URL path? There can't be a URL path if the CSS is embedded in the SVG file.

Comment: I meant the `background: url('tick.svg')`.  The I'm using an external css file. I want to be able to control the stroke color from my main css (external).

Comment: You're dead in the water then as that's not possible. An SVG used as a background image must be complete in a single file. No external references allowed.

Comment: oh! should the svg be in an `img` tag to be able to update its stroke color?

Comment: only `<object>` `<embed>` and `<iframe>` have a DOM. So `<img>` is no use to you. Inline SVG is easiest.

Comment: Can you show how I could update my svg's circle using an `object` tag?

Comment: There are existing questions that cover that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg

Comment: Thank you. I saw your stackoverflow profile and I was so happy to be able to communicate with you. :) I would be grateful if you could show me this as I'm going to be involve working with in inline svg in my carrier.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87021/discussion-between-robert-longson-and-becky).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS to style individual parts of an SVG, you should be using the SVG inline rather than loading an SVG file as a background image.

Chris Coyier wrote an article called [Using SVG](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/), which gives a good overview of the different ways you can use SVGs and the limitations of each approach.

[Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/dmbaughman/pen/oXOVXE) I made of a simple inline SVG with some basic styles applied.  Aside from changing the `stroke` and `fill` properties, you can apply all sorts of styles to inline SVGs, regardless of how complex the shapes are.

```
<!-- HTML -->

<svg width="720" height="120">
  <circle class="foo" cx="90" cy="60" r="40"></circle>
  <circle class="bar" cx="180" cy="60" r="40"></circle>
  <circle class="baz" cx="270" cy="60" r="40"></circle>
</svg>
```

```
/* CSS */

.foo {
  /* default styles */
}
.bar {
  fill: blue;
}
.baz {
  fill: red;
  stroke: blue;
}
```

Hope this helps!