# Changing SVG color on hover inside span called as another style

Tags: html, css, svg

Hello I would like to know how I can select the SVG inside span and change it's color on hover.

My svg is called from another style inside span:

```
<a href="#"><div><span class=icon over"></span></div></a>
```

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
a:hover > div > span { fill: #fff; }
```

But it is not working on the SVG. on the actual span it is working with other property.

So the question is how I can change the color of the SVG which is called with another style which contains svg inside the span element.

SVG Code:

```
.icon{

background: url(../img/sprite.view.svg) no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    text-indent: -9000px;
    white-space: nowrap;

}

.over {
    background-position: 80.45977011494253% 26.016260162601625%;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
}
```

Comment: Is it an inline svg? Because you haven't got an svg in your markup..

Comment: yes it is inline svg

Comment: So... *not* inline SVG  then.

Comment: Check my answer and you will see what inline means and how you can operate on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason to as why it's not working is because you can't change any colors when importing the SVG through an `img` tag, `object` tag or as a `background` of an element.

In order to manipulate an SVG with CSS it must be inline, inline as in:

```
<a href="#">
  <div class="svg-container">
    <svg></svg>
  </div>
</a>
```

Change your markup to what I've done above, with the entire SVG file inside the `div`, then apply the CSS like this:

```
.svg-container {

  > svg {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: #000;
  }
}
```

As someone pointed out you can, however, change an `object` tag with Javascript should you need to use that instead of an inline SVG, should the SVG be really big.

Comment: You **can** do it via object if you use javascript to inject the CSS. You are correct that it's not possible via img and background though.

Comment: @RobertLongson Is that so? I tried about 2 weeks ago but it didn't want to work. Perhaps I missed something vital.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't think I have the code anymore, so it's not an issue :P

Comment: [Erik explains how to do it here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg)