# How do I change the color of a SVG image on hovering its embedding object

Tags: html, css, svg

I embedded an SVG file as object as follows

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="img/icon-info.svg" id='ree' style="width:20px;height:20px;">
```

I did the styling inside the SVG file as follows:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
        g {
            fill: red;
            stroke: blue;
            stroke-width: 3
        }
    ]]>
</style>
```

My question now is, how do I change its color/fill by hovering over the embedding object in the Html file?

Comment: Not sure you can TBH

Comment: Not sure what you mean with TBH

Comment: To Be Honest is what TBH means - And the answer is kinda - See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906148/how-to-apply-a-style-to-an-embedded-svg

Comment: put g:hover styling in the styling inside the SVG file.

Comment: When I put the hover inside the SVG file, the hover effect will only invoked when there is hovering over the outlines of the image. Empty spaces will not invoke the hover. That's why I like the hover effect to be invoked when hovering over the  object