# contentDocument in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have the following js script to access elements inside a object (SVG -         `<object data="bbbbbb.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="alphasvg" width="100%" height="100%"></object>`
)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(window).load(function () {


        var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");
        var svgDoc = a.contentDocument; 
        var delta = svgDoc.getElementsByTagName("path");    
        $(delta).click(function() {

            //do stuff

        })

    });
});
```

I want to use jQuery to access the elements and tags. I'm completely stuck on the contentDocument part.  How can I convert this to jQuery so I can use attr etc?

I want to be able to access and modify attributes in jQuery instead of having to use the traditional js methods which I am unfamiliar with.

How someone can help me?

Thanks a million.

Comment: are you trying to access in-line frame values?

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to access the paths directly like elements, no need for contentDocument or getElementsByTagName, etc:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(window).load(function () {

        $("#alphasvg path").click(function() {

            //do stuff
            // $(this).attr('d') = the path

        })

    });
});
```

Comment: this is correct, the nice thing about svg is the elements are all accessible through the DOM

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
$(svgDoc).find("whatever").doWhatever();
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/pMkG7/show/) and [code here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/pMkG7/). Note that I've used an `<iframe>` for demonstration hence the first URL will work, second will give you "permission denied" error if you try to *run* the fiddle.

Comment: I was still getting same origin issues (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript/3379830#comment25937521_3379830) when I ran without a server, so use a server, even for just client-side js and html as in these examples.

Answer (score 2):

If you are embedding SVG into HTML using the object tag (as opposed to inline SVG), this then this is a duplicate of a previous question, the answer to which may be found here: [How to access SVG elements with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript/3379830#3379830)