# JavaScript accessing inner DOM of SVG

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

`test.php` is a SVG object that's being generated with PHP.

```
<object data="test.php" type="image/svg+xml" id="SVG" />
<script>
    var mySVG = document.getElementById("SVG");
    var svgDoc = mySVG.contentDocument;
```

`svgDoc` is null.  (and so I can't access the elements of the svg via JS.)  It should work, looking at [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript)  What am I doing wrong?  How can I get the `contentDocument` of my SVG?

Comment: Does the `<script>` come after the `<object>` in the actual markup?

Comment: Did you notice, that in the referred answer, the script is executed after the `load` event on the SVG fired? Maybe that's your problem.

Comment: Yes, it does.  I already made that mistake....

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to wait until the SVG is loaded and than you can access the contentDocument:

```
 var mySVG = document.getElementById("SVG");
 var svgDoc;
 mySVG.addEventListener("load",function() {
      svgDoc = mySVG.contentDocument;
      alert("SVG contentDocument Loaded!");
 }, false);
```

Comment: I also found (in addition to above) that it returned null when I was trying to access a svg via something like this: `data="../otherdir/images/mysvg.svg"` (at least locally, can't test online at the moment), though `data="images/mysvg.svg"` works.

Comment: It does not work for me, I get always null

Answer (score 21):

Not sure this is an answer, but it worked for me.
I had the same problem and `svgObject` was returning `null`:

`var svgObject = document.getElementById('svgObject').contentDocument;`

Then it occurred to me that I was running my html page locally: file:///C:/wwwroot/App_dev/OverLay/Overlay03.html

Running it from the server:
http://localhost:62551/App_dev/OverLay/Overlay03.html

It worked flawlessly and `svgObject` returned its content, then I could get the `div` inside it.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This also bit me! `python3 -m http.server`to the rescue!

Comment: This is it! This marks the end of many hours of debugging, thank you!

Comment: Thank you. This bit me on Firefox, too.

Comment: To set the port, do something like `python -m http.server 8001`