# Gaining access to the SVG DOM in Chrome and Safari through Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, webkit

I'm trying to display an SVG scaled to the size of the object so a 600x600 svg get scaled to fit a 500x500 object or a 300x300 whatever.
This all works just fine in FireFox but Safari and Chrome (Webkit) just crop the SVG

```
<div class="svg">
<object id="diagram" type="image/svg+xml" class="emb-diag" data="my.svg">
</object>
</div>


// Class method 
setViewBox : function(objectSVG, containerSize, viewboxSize)
{
    objectSVG.setAttribute("width", containerSize);
    objectSVG.setAttribute("height", containerSize);

    var svgDoc;
    if ( typeof objectSVG.getSVGDocument != 'undefined')
    {
        svgDoc = objectSVG.getSVGDocument();
        if (svgDoc == null)
        {
            svgDoc = objectSVG.contentDocument;
            if (svgDoc == null)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        svgDoc = objectSVG.contentDocument;
        if (svgDoc == null)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    var svgElem = svgDoc.documentElement;
    if (svgElem)
    {
        svgElem.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + viewboxSize + " " + viewboxSize);
        svgElem.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "xMinYMin meet");
    }
},

TheClass.setViewBox(document.getElementById("diagram"), 500, 600);
```

When debug in Safari this line

```
var svgElem = svgDoc.documentElement;
```

interrepts the svgElem variable as an HTMLHtmlElement as does Chrome

```
svgDoc: HTMLDocument
svgElem: **HTMLHtmlElement**
accessKey: ""
attributes: NamedNodeMap
baseURI: "about:blank"
childElementCount: 2
childNodes: NodeList[2]
children: HTMLCollection[2]
classList: DOMTokenList
className: ""
clientHeight: 500
clientLeft: 0
clientTop: 0
clientWidth: 500
contentEditable: "inherit"
dataset: DOMStringMap
dir: ""
```

...

Chrome does report the following

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/svg+xml:
"file:///my.svg". jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.o jquery.min.js:2
f.Callbacks.p.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
c.addEventListener.B
```

But I get that - but why? My Googling activities shed no light on the matter.

FireFox interrepts it as :
As proper SVG DOM the whole SVG file can be expanded as you'd expect

Just preempt I've been down the  route already that even worse both these lines both return null
            svgDoc = objectSVG.getSVGDocument();
            svgDoc = objectSVG.contentDocument;

FireFox is fine Safari and Chrome don't scale

I can do it with an  and scaling works but the svgDoc remains null but there's no access to the SVG DOM and that's what I want.

I've not tested the SVG inline variant but I really don't want to have to go down that route if at all possible.

If anybody out there has been down this path before me, thrashing through the undergrowth along the way, then your insights would be very much appreciated.

Comment: The question still stands but a work around is here

this just leaves me thinking what's different about the way in which (or order in which) webkit vs mozilla loads SVG documents.

Curiouser and cursiouser! Would like to understand what's going on.

Comment: Noticed the above work around is good for Safari but fails in Chrome. Also it's god for Safari on OS X (may be windows) but not iOS. Seems to be a variety of support for manipulating the SVG DOM across the browser eco-system.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to access the contentDocument until the onload event of the `<object>` element has fired. Try moving the TheClass.setViewBox call into the onload handler e.g.

```
<object onload="TheClass.setViewBox..."
```

Comment: Or for a non-inline solution, add an addEventListener (see example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434916/javascript-accessing-inner-dom-of-svg). I kept getting the null problem in Chrome too (haven't checked Safari).