# getSVGDocument is returning NULL in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm starting to use SVG and I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<embed id="embed" src="svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="400" height="300" >

<object id="object" data="svg.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="400" height="300"></object>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(window).load(function (){
//alert("Document loaded, including graphics and embedded documents (like SVG)");

    var svgDoc_embed = document.getElementById("embed").getSVGDocument();
    alert("My svgDoc_embed => " + svgDoc_embed);

    var svgDoc_object = document.getElementById("object").getSVGDocument();
    alert("My svgDoc_object => " + svgDoc_object);  

});
```

**In the FireFox browser works well**

```
My svgDoc_embed => [object SVGDocument]
My svgDoc_object => [object SVGDocument]
```

**but does not work on Chrome browser.**

```
My svgDoc_embed => null
My svgDoc_object => null
```

I have searched the Internet but can not find anything that works

Any suggestion is welcome

==========================================================================

I try opening the Chrome JS console and type in:

`document.getElementById ("object"). GetSVGDocument ();`

The result is null.

Also change the code to:

```
$ ("embed"). load (function () {
svgDoc_embed var = document.getElementById ("embed"). getSVGDocument ();
alert ("My # embed svgDoc_embed =>" + svgDoc_embed);
});

  $ ("object"). load (function () {
  svgDoc_object var = document.getElementById ("object"). getSVGDocument ();
alert ("My # object svgDoc_object =>" + svgDoc_object);
  });
```

And does not give any results.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Does contentDocument work in Chrome? i.e. document.getElementById("embed").contentDocument

Comment: getSVGDocument() works on Chrome on one of my servers but not the other. Maybe it's the password protection? contentDocument returns null also. firstElementChild is null also.

Comment: Apparently you have to wait for it to load first, then `contentDocument` seems to work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434916/javascript-accessing-inner-dom-of-svg

Comment: I have the same issue when trying to use GetSVGDocument from the local filesystem rather than http or https.  It seems to be a security issue.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52693026/ and Serge's answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22529398/

Answer (score 2):

I believe getSVGDocument() is deprecated and didn't work in my copy of FF. Try using firstElementChild instead:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("object").firstElementChild;
```

or access the SVG element directly with:

```
var svg = document.getElementById("foo");
```

Where "foo" is the value of the id attribute of the root svg element.

```
<svg id="foo">
```

Comment: When you insert <svg> element inline, it doesn't form separate SVG document. It becomes a part of outer HTML document. When SVG is embedded with <object>, however, it is contained it's own document.

Comment: I couldn't find any info on `getSVGDocument()` being deprecated. Plus, it [supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=getSVGDocument) by most of the browsers at the moment.