# getSVGDocument and contentDocument return null in chrome

Tags: object, svg

I have two different HTML pages using the same svg file I'm inserting with the  tag.

The problem is I can retrieve the contentDocument in one of them but not the other. I opened inspect in both pages and the objects look exactly the same.

This is the one that does not work:

```
> document.getElementById("agvObj")
<object type=​"image/​svg+xml" data=​"agv/​agv.svg" class=​"agvObj" id=​"agvObj" height=​"100" width=​"100" style=​"visibility:​hidden;​">
    ​#document
        xml-stylesheet
        <svg xmlns=​"http:​/​/​www.w3.org/​2000/​svg" xmlns:xlink=​"http:​/​/​www.w3.org/​1999/​xlink" width=​"100" height=​"100" id=​"agvSVG">​…​</svg>​
</object>​
> document.getElementById("agvObj").getSVGDocument()
null
> document.getElementById("agvObj").contentDocument
null
```

This is the one that works:

```
> document.getElementById("agvObj")
<object type=​"image/​svg+xml" data=​"agv/​agv.svg" class=​"agvObj" id=​"agvObj" height=​"100" width=​"100" style=​"visibility:​hidden;​">
    ​#document
        xml-stylesheet
        <svg xmlns=​"http:​/​/​www.w3.org/​2000/​svg" xmlns:xlink=​"http:​/​/​www.w3.org/​1999/​xlink" width=​"100" height=​"100" id=​"agvSVG">​…​</svg>​
</object>​
> document.getElementById("agvObj").getSVGDocument()
#document
> document.getElementById("agvObj").contentDocument
#document
```

The object looks exactly the same, so I really don't know what else I should check to know why it works in one page and not the other.

Comment: Is there any difference in how these pages are loaded?  Are you waiting until the SVG is loaded before trying to access the DOM?

Comment: Yes, there is a difference, I realised yesterday. One page was opened a file:// url and the other one as http:// url. Only the latter worked I guess file:// does not work for some security reason.

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3510578/923560