# SVG is accessible when embedded but not when included

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have a map with SVG and I am going to create an Area Map with that. It works well when I embed that SVG file in my HTML page, but not when I include it by

This is my SVG:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="595.28px" height="841.89px" viewBox="0 0 595.28 841.89" enable-background="new 0 0 595.28 841.89" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_1">
    <rect x="106.429" y="86.429" fill="#D32A2A" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="311.429" height="194.286"/>
</g>
<g id="Layer_2">
    <rect x="127.144" y="261.143" fill="#1F5785" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="311.428" height="194.287"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

And this is my javascript:

```
$(function(){
      $('#Layer_2').click(function() {
            alert('Thanks');
        });
    });
```

This works well and when I click on blue square, an alert shows. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tnad1Ly1/)

But I need to include it like this:

```
<object data="map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="map-id" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

and when I include it, I don't have access to that. [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ragayumuhu/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You right this don't work...

> You need for use "live" bind, because when you include it directly it
>   load in not same time as your script:
>
> ```
>     $('#Layer_2').live('click', function() {
>         alert('Thanks');
>     });
> ```

I have found this solutions [first for read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434916/javascript-accessing-inner-dom-of-svg), [second for read](http://benfrain.com/selecting-svg-inside-tags-with-javascript/)
To access svg.contentDocument it must be loaded from the same domain, and it will be null otherwise.
There working [DEMO](http://193.106.43.227:8081/demo/).

for simlify your use svg as inside you must start your code after loading all svg objects:

```
<object id="mysvg1" data="./test.svg" type="image/svg+xml"  width="100%" height="100%"></object>
<object id="mysvg2" data="./test.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
...
var my_start_function = function(){
  // start your code here
}
...
var svg_objects = ['mysvg1','mysvg2'], load_counter = 0;
for (var i in svg_objects) {
   document.getElementById(svg_objects[i]).addEventListener("load",function() {
    load_counter++;
    if (load_counter == svg_objects.length) my_start_function();
  }, false);
}
```

and access to svg elements throught a little function:

```
var svg_inside = function(svg_id,elem_id) { 
    return $($(document.getElementById(svg_id.substr(1)).contentDocument).find(elem_id)[0]);
}
...
svg_inside('#mysvg1','#Layer_2').click(function() {
    alert('Thanks');
});
```

Comment: that is not my source and I know that, But I need that way that my code is, and you didn't use live. Thanks anyway

Comment: I a little don't understand you. What way you need? What about this?
` $(function(){ var my_start_function = function(svg) { var my_svg_elem = $(svg).find('#Layer_2')[0]; $(my_svg_elem).click(function() { alert('Thanks'); }); } var mySVG = document.getElementById("map-id"); mySVG.addEventListener("load",function() { my_start_function(mySVG.contentDocument); }, false); });`

Comment: Please look at your answer, You used `live` but on your demo you didn't use that way. Please read my question again, I need the way what is in my code

Comment: I think that I have understand you. But there no any different way. And no way for using live and jquery both.

Comment: I need to do it just by jquery and having direct access to SVG path by call it like `$("#path")` I can do it when embedded but I need to do it when I use it with object

Comment: Can you please change your demo?