# SVG vector changing fill not working

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I'm trying to change fill color on my SVG file. But no one from methods is working. I was trying a lot of, but I can't even get object which I want to.

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="map.svg" height="500" id="world_map">
    Your browser does not support SVG.
    <script src="draw.js"></script>
</object>
```

This is my SVG declaration and script src.

And script is

```
var x = $('#world_map#path1622');
console.log(x);
```

But it is not working. It isn't even return the good element. I've tried code with it but it's not working too.

Comment: Your jQuery is invalid; you're probably looking for a space before `#path1622`. You also don't appear to have jQuery defined.

Comment: Its not this. Ive just made my code shorter,and posted most important things.
I've had var x = $('#path1622'); before and i've had same problem. It cannot get to this path

And i don't have error. Its finding #path1622 but when i check this object propeties there is no css,no id and other things,which are in svg code

Comment: Your svg document is a framed element, to access it, you need to request the framed document from the `<object>` element's `contentDocument`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript accessing inner DOM of SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434916/javascript-accessing-inner-dom-of-svg)

Comment: Still not working and didnt find anwser.

$(window).bind('load',function()  {
  var mySvgObject = $('#objectid');
  console.log(mySvgObject);
  $('object#objectid#id_of_element').style("fill", "white");;
})

Even with
$(mySvgObject).find('#elementid').style("fill", "white");

Comment: The thing i try to color is <path id="pathid" style="fill:black"></path>

Comment: My svg is svg/xml does it matters?

Answer (score -1):

I think i have a tip.
My svg file is like
-Object
  -#document
    -svg

And i have to to the code like

```
var content = $("").contents();
```

I have to make access to the document,object or svg?