# How to get SVG to scale to full height and width of parent container using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG of baseball diamond, and I'm trying to set its width and height via the attributes of its parent container.

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a5mz90jy/6/

Here's my Javascript:

```
const svgBaseballField = document.getElementById('diamond');
  console.log(svgBaseballField);
  const svgContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('svg_container');
  console.log(svgContainer);

  const svgContainerHeight = svgContainer.clientHeight;
  console.log(svgContainerHeight);
  const svgContainerWidth = svgContainer.clientWidth;

  svgBaseballField.setAttribute("width", svgContainerWidth);
  svgBaseballField.setAttribute("height", svgContainerHeight);

  svgBaseballField.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 100 100");
```

I know something is wrong, because svgContainerHeight and svgContainerWidth are undefined. I also know I need to set the viewport to something.

I also checked this before:
[How can I make an svg scale with its parent container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484707/how-can-i-make-an-svg-scale-with-its-parent-container)

Comment: basically, I want the svg to scale to the parent container.

Comment: width="100%" height="100%"

Comment: I am confused, it is not working for me.

Comment: You edited the SVG and changed its height and width to 100% and that doesn't produce the rendering you want?

Comment: editing the SVG directly worked, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG you are linking to has a fixed `width` and `height` (650 x 500), so you are not going to be able to do it the way you are doing now (ie. via `<object>`.

You have two options:

1. Copy the SVG locally and modify it.  Add a `viewBox` attribute and change the `width` and `height` to `"100%"`.

   ```
   <svg ... width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 650 500" ... >
   ```
2. The other solution is to include the SVG as a background image and take advantage of the CSS background sizing properties.

   ```
   .svg_container {
     width: 75%;
     height: 100%;
     background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Baseball_diamond_clean.svg) blue;
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-size: contain;
   }
   ```

   https://jsfiddle.net/a5mz90jy/12/

Comment: number one works better for me, thanks! And because I am using the object tag, I still have access to all the XML content, right? (if I wanted to change the fill color of a base in JavaScript, etc) ?

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble selecting the elements in the SVG. I'm using D3 to select them, and I can't. do you think you can post an example in the fiddle? Should I be importing the SVG in D3.xml, or is the <object> tag sufficient enough to do it?

Comment: You can't access the SVG directly, you have to access it via the `contentDocument` property of the `<object>`.  Are you doing that?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434916/javascript-accessing-inner-dom-of-svg