# Dynamically loaded SVG won't let access to its DOM

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg

Following [CSS-Tricks guide on SVG sprites](https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/) I've done a [SVG sprites file](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kumiau/temprepo/menu_sprites.svg) that have inside several `symbol` elements with `animate` elements that can trigger an animation when the `beginElement()` function is run on them.

This works well when I insert the svg in my HTML, but I want to caché this SVG. I've follow the [CSS-Trick Guide on Ajaxing this SVG Sprites](https://css-tricks.com/ajaxing-svg-sprite/) and I'm loading this SVG dinamically, but after load I've not been able to access the DOM of the SVG to run  the `beginElement()` function.

The problem is that the `contentDocument` attribute is null in the loaded SVG. I've found that there's an `ownerDocument` attribute with the DOM, but it looks like it's read-only. When I try to run `beginElement()` nothing happens.

You can see the problem in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kumiau/2hx5gnc6/2/

I've found this problem reported in other SO threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434916/javascript-accessing-inner-dom-of-svg)) but they boild down to two main problems:

- `file://` protocol, but I'm running this on a server.
- External domain file, but I'm loading my SVG from the same domain.
- SVG not loaded, but I'm running my code after the SVG is downloaded.

Comment: Firefox, at least, seems to implement `<use>` as a shadow DOM container. Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16656262/367865) has something useful.

Comment: it's just document to access things