# How to add event listeners to objects in a svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I would like to create a web page displaying an interactive svg: since several svg may be used, the various objects displayed will have different IDs, so the event listeners (to catch a mouse click, for example) have to be dynamic.

Starting from [this snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript/3379830#3379830)

```
var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");
a.addEventListener("load",function(){
        var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
        var delta = svgDoc.getElementById("delta");
        delta.addEventListener("click",function(){alert('hello world!')},false);
    },false);
```

I would like to find a way to cycle through all the objects of the svg (maybe having a particular class) and attach an even listener to them.

**update**

So JQuery 'each' function may be a suitable option, but it seems that JQuery doesn't handle the svg DOM so well. Is there any other available option? (like a JQuery plugin?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is my preferred structure for adding event listeners to SVG elements with vanilla js...

```
// select elements
var elements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('svg .selector'));

// add event listeners
elements.forEach(function(el) {
   el.addEventListener("touchstart", start);
   el.addEventListener("mousedown",  start);
   el.addEventListener("touchmove",  move);
   el.addEventListener("mousemove",  move);
})

// event listener functions

function start(e){
  console.log(e);
  // just an example
}

function move(e){
  console.log(e);
  // just an example
}
```

The sample code you present is somewhat contrived, but here's a rewrite that makes it work...

```
var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");
a.addEventListener("load",function(){
  var svgDoc = a.contentDocument;
  var els = svgDoc.querySelectorAll(".myclass");
  for (var i = 0, length = els.length; i < length; i++) {
    els[i].addEventListener("click", 
       function(){ console.log("clicked"); 
    }, false);
  }
},false);
```

Comment: Should a.contentDocument not be els[i].contentDocument?

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert not really, but the entire example was wrong, I rewrote it.