# Is this a correct use of an eventListerner in JavaScript? SVG not responding to event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have a SVG nested in a div, and it appears I have to duplicate the `title` tag information from the encapsulated div on the `svg` image in order for the `event` to fire as well.

HTML:

```
<div id="1" title="belief" class="list mix category-1" data-myorder="1">
    <img class="crest" data-myorder="1" src="public/images/belief.svg" title="belief" alt="belief">
</div>
```

I tried to add the `pointer-events` property to the elements, which I thought would help, but strangely that did nothing!

CSS:

```
.crest {
   ...other styles...
    pointer-events: all !important;

}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function templateLoader(e) {
        var doc = document,
            event = EventUtility.getEvent(e),
            target = EventUtility.getTarget(event),
            id = event.target.id,
            title = event.target.title;


        if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {


            console.log(id);
            $.Mustache.options.warnOnMissingTemplates = true;

            $.Mustache.load('./public/js/templates/templates.html')
                .fail(function() {
                    $('body').append('Failed to load templates from <code>templates.html</code>');
                })
                .done(function() {

                    $('body').append($.Mustache.render(title, {
                        coreIdeas: title
                    }));

                    $('#appButton').on('click', function() {
                        $('#overlay').remove();
                    });

                });


        }

        EventUtility.stopPropagation(event);
    }

    var flimFlam = document.getElementById('Container');
    EventUtility.addHandler(flimFlam, 'click', templateLoader);

});
```

**UPDATE:** Added Container div below

```
<div id="Container" class="container">
    <div id="1" title="belief" class="list mix category-1" data-myorder="1"><img class="crest" data-myorder="1" src="public/images/belief.svg" title="belief" alt="belief">
    </div>

    <div id="2" title="integrity" class="list mix category-1" data-myorder="2">
        <img class="crest" src="public/images/integrity.svg" alt="integrity">
    </div>

    <div id="3" title="respect" class="list mix category-1" data-myorder="3">
        <img class="crest" src="public/images/respect.svg" alt="respect"
    </div>

    <div id="4" title="trust" class="list mix category-2" data-myorder="4"
        <img class="crest" src="public/images/trust.svg" alt="trust">
    </div>
```

[image: demo of click area]

**UPDATE:**
I have been prompted to try to reiterate what I'd like to accomplish.

Right now, despite the div wrapping around the `svg` the `click` event will not respond when clicking on the `svg`

```
###########################
# svg # ***************** #    This is the div when in list form
###########################

##########
#*      *#
#   svg  #     This is the div in grid mode
#*      *#
##########
```

The div in list form responds to a click where the asterisks are, but if you tried in the area where the `svg` resides, the handler won't fire because the svg is blocking it.

In the grid mode, you really can only get it to fire around the edges of the `svg`

Hope this helps!

```
<div id="1" title="belief" class="list mix category-1" data-myorder="1">
    <img class="crest" data-myorder="1" src="public/images/belief.svg" title="belief" alt="belief">
</div>
```

Comment: i think you are leaving out an important piece of code? i dont see the ID "Container"  being assigned anywhere in the HTML

Comment: @RAEC - Ugh thanks! I forgot! I just updated the `HTML`

Comment: is that you true HTML? your image elements have to end in "/>" not ">"; your div with id 4 is missing its ">"; last, your div Container is not closed (missing </div>) although this last one i assume is because you did not post the entire file which is fine.

Comment: @RAEC - Thanks, but not sure if the  `/>` matters; check out these examples: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4476526/do-i-use-img-object-or-embed-for-svg-files, And I check the `#Container` div is closed locally, but thanks!

Comment: did you also check the div with id 4? is is missing its ">"; Also, your image within id 3 is missing its "/>" or its ">". Also, i could be wrong, but my understanding is that inside an SVG, you can end the img with ">" but not in HTML outside the SVG (i could be wrong). anyway, fix the two elemetns that are not closed at all first.

Comment: Thanks `RAEC` However, that didn't work.

Comment: also, can you tell me what exactly it is you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add event listeners to objects in a svg?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451855/how-to-add-event-listeners-to-objects-in-a-svg)

Comment: @ RAEC: updated the question...

Comment: What is `EventUtility`?

Comment: @hjpotter - It's a object to deal with differences in the way browsers handle `events`—pretty handy. I know, that's what `jquery` is for, but I wanted to better understand what's going on.

Comment: Can you create a MCVE using the snippet button (looks like (https://stackoverflow.com/content/balsamiq/wmd-mockup-button.png?v=4 )?

Comment: @hjpotter - I hosted it on dropbbox - https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1177179/app/index.html