# Attaching load event to object tag is not firing with aurelia

Tags: javascript, svg, aurelia, custom-element

I have a popup which will gets called when a button clicked and it contains the video from external link.

```
<object style="width: 696px; height: 360px;;display:block;" 
                id="educational-info-video-widget"
                name="educational-info-video-widget" data="https_URL" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
                <param name="movie" value="https_URL">
                <param name="flashvars" value="&amp;autoPlay=false">
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true">
                <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
            </object>
```

what i am trying to do is attaching play and pause events to it, to do so i saw that it needs to implemented in load event from this link.

[How to add event listeners to objects in a svg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451855/how-to-add-event-listeners-to-objects-in-a-svg)

I wrote this in my .js file

```
constructor() {
   this.handleBodyClick = function() {
            alert()
        };
}

 attached() {
        document.getElementById("educational-info-video-widget").addEventListener("load", this.handleBodyClick);
    }
```

but load event is not being fired. i don't know what i am doing wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your content is not cached in browser? Then your load event may have fired before you attached your handler. Try to set again the `data`attribute after you've attached the event.

Answer (score 0):

The `load` event is only supported with the following tags.

- `<body>`
- `<frame>`
- `<frameset>`
- `<iframe>`
- `<img>`
- `<input type="image">`
- `<link>`
- `<script>`
- `<style>`

Comment: Yeah... what about audio video object SVGImage embed... ?

Comment: Kaiido, are you saying my answer is incorrect or incomplete?

Comment: Hum both actually, since what it implies is that there is no load event for the object element, while there is.

Comment: More info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679704/what-html-tags-support-the-onload-onerror-javascript-event-attributes .

Comment: Yep look at the second answer, accepted one is wrong.