# Is there a neat way to extract all elements from an SVG doc and place them in a html text box?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to give the user an ability to manually edit an SVG document.

Is there a strait forward way to use DOM to extract all the elements from an SVG document and place it in a text box? I tried to use innerHTML but that didn't work (not available for SVG).

Is there a method within JavaScript to extract all SVG elements from an embedded SVG document and store them as a string? I don't want to use jQuery or plugin if I can avoid it..

Sorry for my wording, my english is very poor.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `XMLSerializer` to do this.

```
var str = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgDocument);
```

If you have an `<object>` tag that references the svg, your `svgDocument` variable should be set to something like `yourObjectElm.contentDocument`. If the svg is inline in the html, then you can pass the  element(s) instead of the document.