# Manipulating SVG via javascript, stuck on load event

Tags: javascript, svg

I have been trying to access parts of an SVG image via javascript. The images in a external file (same domain) being manipulated by an external js file (same domain).

Example like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script defer="defer" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script defer="defer" src="controls.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="spikeroad" src="map.svg" alt="loadbarspike"/>
</body>
```

I have asked this question previously: [Can getElementByID decend into SVG docs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830653/can-getelementbyid-decend-into-svg-docs)

I have read that and taking into account the feedback from others seen here: [How to access SVG elements with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript) including all the extra answers but I can not seem to get this to work.

Is  a black box when it comes to events and will I need to use ? There arrears (to me at least) some misinformation around this. My code does not work for either however.

My major sticking point appears (to me) to be making the 'load' event fire.

This is my latest version:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    'use strict';
    $(window).on("load", function () {
        var svgContainer = document.getElementById("spikeroad");
        var svgDoc = svgContainer.contentDocument;
        var inner = svgDoc.getElementById("innerrect");
        inner.addEventListener("mousedown", function() {
            console.debug('inner box was clicked');
        }, false);
    }, false);
});
```

Any more feedback would be really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you call $(window).on("load"...) inside of $(document).ready(...)? It doesn't need to be nested like this.

Comment: You can't manipulate svg if it's in img tag. You need to put that svg inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the `contentDocument` of an `img` element. It should work if you use an `iframe` instead.