# Get Javascript to work? $.ajax not working right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, hover

So, the Javascript code which can be found below doesn't seem to be functioning properly.

The goal is to get the text below the map to change on hover of the rooms.

[Map Page](http://zadias.me/SVG/PresParkEisenhower.html)

The JSON (zadias.me/SVG/rooms.json) data that pulls the data seems to be where I'm faulting, I think. When I test/debug the code by placing .innerHTML statements that would print in the text field, it would work if I placed the .innerHTML before the $.ajax, however, if I put the .innerHTML function in the "success" part of the .ajax, it wouldn't work..

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var json = (function () { //this function obtains the data
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'http://zadias.me/SVG/rooms.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) { 
            json = data;
        }
    });
    return json;
})();

function hashTag(){
    var hashTag, hash2;

    hashTag = location.hash; //obtains the part of the URL with the hash tag and what follows
    hashTag = hashTag.replace(/#*/, ''); //replaces the hash tag

    if(hashTag.length > 0){
        for(i=0 ; i<json.rooms.length ; i++){
            if (json.rooms[i].roomId == hashTag) //linear search through array of rooms to see if any equal the hashTag
            {
            document.getElementById('room_info').innerHTML = '<img src="images/' + json.rooms[i].image + '" /><h4>' + json.rooms[i].name + '</h4>' + json.rooms[i].HTMLdescrip;
            } //loads the data from the JSON data.
        }
    }
}; 

function setHash(){
    window.location.hash = this.id; //creates the hash link based on the object's id (object id acquired from the JSON data) and sets it
};

function setHTML(){
    for(i=0 ; i<json.rooms.length ; i++){
    if (json.rooms[i].roomId == this.id)
    {
    document.getElementById('room_info').innerHTML = '<img src="images/' + json.rooms[i].image + '" /><h4>' + json.rooms[i].name + '</h4>' + json.rooms[i].HTMLdescrip;
    }
  }
};

window.onload = hashTag();
$(".active").click(setHash);
$(".active").mouseenter(setHTML);
//$(".active").mouseover(setHTML);
$(".active").mouseleave(hashTag);
});
```

I understand that it's a bit localized, how could I change this up?

Comment: Could you post your relevant code here?

Comment: `'async': false,` is a very bad idea.  Locks up the browser during the ajax call.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null` on line 1 of `PresParkEisenhower2.svg`.  `document.body.style` is causing it.

Comment: Thanks @Archer! I got rid of it, I don't seem to see any improvement.. @jfriend00 I tried getting rid of `'async':false`, but it didn't seem to do much.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting it right, you need the variable `json` to be global.  Just take off the `var` at the beginning and see if that helps.

Comment: Worth a try.  The only thing I can suggest is to put some `console.log()` statements in to dump out variable values and check them, or use the debugger and step through the code.

Comment: Which I've now done.  Mouse-over only returns an element with the id of svg.  Looks like you can't select the rooms in the way you are doing.  (Go to console and enter `$(".active")`).

Comment: I'm rather new to Javascript and I'm not too familiar with console.log(). I'll do some research on it and hopefully it'll help. Thanks for the help!

Comment: From further reading it looks difficult to parse an svg element in the manner you're trying.  I'd do some googling on that first.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something more along these lines:

```
// this returns a promise
var json,
    response = $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'http://zadias.me/SVG/rooms.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) { 
            json = data;
        }
    });

window.onload = function() {
    // ensures that the ajax has returned a value
    response.done(hashTag);
};
```

The document doesn't really have to be ready for you to run an AJAX request.

You may want to take a look here for accessing the SVG elements: [How to access SVG elements with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript). Requires a change from <embed> to <object>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version of your code with a few updates:

```
var json;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        'global': false,
        'url': 'http://zadias.me/SVG/rooms.json',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
            hashTag();
            $(".active")
                .click(setHash)
                .mouseenter(setHTML)
                .mouseleave(hashTag);
        }
    });
});

function hashTag(){
    //get everything in the URL after the #
    var hash = location.hash.replace(/#*/, '');

    if(hash.length > 0){
        //linear search through array of rooms to find the hashTag
        $.each( json.rooms, function( room ) {
            if (room.roomId == hash) {
                $('#room_info').html(
                    '<img src="images/' + room.image + '" /><h4>' +
                    room.name + '</h4>' + room.HTMLdescrip
                );
            } //loads the data from the JSON data.
        });
    }
};

 // creates the hash link based on the object's id
 // (object id acquired from the JSON data) and sets it
function setHash(){
    window.location.hash = this.id;
}

function setHTML(){
    $.each( json.rooms, function( room ) {
        if (room.roomId == this.id) {
            $('#room_info').html(
                '<img src="images/' + room.image + '" /><h4>' +
                room.name + '</h4>' + room.HTMLdescrip
            );
        }
    });
}
```

What I changed:

1. Made the `json` variable global.
2. Removed the `async:true`. Never use that!
3. Removed `global:false`. You don't have any global Ajax event handlers, so this flag has no effect.
4. Removed unnecessary quotes around the `$.ajax()` property names.
5. Removed the event handler setup at the end of the code.
6. Moved that initialization *inside* the `$.ajax()` callback since that is when the data is ready.
7. Chained together the event handler setup on `$(".active")` instead of repeating the selector call.
8. Used `$.each()` instead of the `for` loops for simplicity.
9. Changed the `json.rooms[i]` references to `room` thanks to `$.each()`.
10. Used `$('#foo').html(html) instead of`document.getElementById()`and`.innerHTML`, again for simplicity.
11. Simplified the setup of the `hashTag` variable and changed its name to `hash` to avoid confusion with the function name.
12. Removed unnecessary semicolons at the end of function definitions.
13. Made the indentation and formatting more consistent.
14. Shortened the excessive line lengths.

Some of these changes are just stylistic, but they're things I recommend. Naturally you can pick and choose among those after looking through the code.

The important point is making sure that the `json` data is available not just where it's needed, but *when* it's needed, and without using `async:false`.