# Filling SVG element, working on data from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, svg

Hello I have JSON file with this structure (I have 249 countries, all with iso codes)
and as you can see I want to declare iso code as var iso, and visitors, as var visitors, and then if visistors have more than 1, and less than 50, fill SVG element where ID=iso with #94d31b, but it doesn't work... I don't know what to do now. and before I do "if" I want to fill Canada, but console says that ca does not exist, but I have this element in SVG, and when I delete this line, and put this line into if, then I have no error, so if doesn't work, because if he did, he should say that "ca" does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looping through your `data` incorrectly. You actually want to loop through the `data.iso_countries` array. Try:

```
$.getJSON("results.json", function(data) {
    data = data.iso_countries; // the array we really want
    for(var key in data) {
```

As for how to access individual parts of the SVG image, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript).

Comment: It works, because now if works either, but this I have in console 
TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null
document.getElementById("iso").style.fill="#94d31b";
because I want to get ID by iso, because iso has actual isocode
document.getElementById(iso).style.fill="#94d31b"; if I put document.getElementById(ca).style.fill="#94d31b"; and then console says that ca does not exist, but in SVG Canada has id="ca" :|

Comment: Added a link to an existing question that should help you with that.

Comment: Thank you :) I updated my original post with new data from that link, because now, console says that svgMap is undefined...
TypeError: svgMap is undefined
svgMap.getElementById(iso).style.fill="#94d31b";

Comment: That should be a fairly straightforward fix. If your code has multiple problems, try to narrow them down and post them as separate questions.

Comment: it works! haha but now I don't know why, because if I use <embed to load this SVG, then it doesn't work, if I put whole SVG code just on site, then it works :D do you know why? I mean, do you know why even if I try to take SVG DOM structure, I cant?

Comment: I'm not sure how the DOM views `<embed>` versus `<img>`, but I can't say I'm surprised, either. I think it interprets `<embed>` in the same way as `<iframe>` and considers it a separate document. I may be way off, though.