# Accessing HTMLObjectElement from System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser fails

Tags: javascript, html, .net, svg, webbrowser-control

This HTML is based upon  a previous solution found [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top)

```
<body>
<object data="C:\Dts\AipDirs\Eg\MarsOutputStore\_AD2_LFBD_000.svg" id="alphasvg" width="100%" height="100%" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
<script>
    var a = document.getElementById("alphasvg");

    alert (a); // Displays [object HTMLObjectElement] when page is loaded into IE on desktop, but [object] when loaded into System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser

    // it's important to add an load event listener to the object, as it will load the svg doc asynchronously
    a.addEventListener("load",function(){

        alert ("in addEvenetListener for load");       

    },false);
</script>
```

and this works as I'd expect when I load it into IE (version 10) running on my desktop.  However, when I load it into a WebBrowser object in a UserControl it doesn't work - the alert returns a different object (see comment on that line) and it then complains that:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
```

Why does WebBrowser not behave like IE on the desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seemed to fix it:

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

WebBrowser and IE have different default compatibility modes for intranet documents and I was loading the HTML file from the local file system.  Maybe that's got something to do with it?