# On click svg image path get path id?

Tags: jquery, svg, snap.svg

I tried to get an id of svg image path ,but it's not working ,on DOM ready i have tried it on document ready also i have tried.How can i get it done.I have used svg image (NewTux.svg) from this url http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div id="main_wrapper">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="NewTux.svg">Your browser does not support SVG</object>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/snapsvg/0.1.0/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('path').click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });

    /*$(window).load(function(){
        $('path').click(function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });*/

</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your SVG image contains actually `path` elements inside of it? As you know, the SVG graphic is in fact an XML text file, open it and check the contents with simple text editor.

Comment: inside `path` elements are there i have checked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access SVG elements with Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are importing the `svg` from a file. If you include the `svg` markup on your page your code will work.

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f1gsyp7u/)

I think this is because when you import it the `svg` markup isn't loaded on the page yet so it cannot attach events to the `path` elements.

I did find a answer on StackOverflow that does address this. What you have to do is attach a load event to the `object` that when fired will attached your click events once it has been loaded.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753732/how-to-access-svg-elements-with-javascript) answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you embed your svg doc into an `<object>` element, then you have to check for its [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Property/contentDocument) property and make the searches from the [`documentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement) there.

I don't know well `jQuery`, but I think it's quite lame about `svg`, and I don't know too much either about other libraries, but here is [`vannila.js`](http://vanilla-js.com) code :

```
document.querySelector('object').addEventListener('load',function(){
    var p = this.contentDocument.documentElement.querySelectorAll('path');
    for(i=0;i<p.length;i++){
     p[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ 
          alert("Hello my name is "+this.id+"…")
        });
    }
});
```

[▶︎ Show Live Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/XlSE8klCjRzqYsihof4g?p=preview)

Note that you'll have to wait for the object has loaded its `data` and that you're restricted by the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `object` for event triggering:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('object').on("click", function(){
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
 });
```