# How to select a specific path ID in jquery

Tags: jquery, dom, gsap, articulate-storyline

I'm trying to select the object that uniqueDomID-227 refers to in this line of code, but don't have any luck in doing so.

```
<path id="uniqueDomId-227" fill="#4F81BD" fill-opacity="1" stroke="#385D8A" 
stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="flat" stroke-
linejoin="round" d="M0,0 L96,0 96,80 0,80Z" data-stroke-sharpened="true" 
transform="translate(0.5, 0.5)" data-accepts="events" data-
reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$6APsFT39tH6.0.3:$c202.1:$c203.2.$0.$0.$0"></path>
```

I've tried using document.getElementById and jquery but no luck so far. I'm guessing I'm missing something, so any suggestions would be appreciated. This is from an Articulate Storyline course and trying to select an object to transform with Greensock.

There is no other unique ID for this element - there are multiple classes with duplicate names, so as far as I can see this is the only unique ID for the object.

Comment: `$("#uniqueDomId-227")`?

Comment: try `console.log($("#uniqueDomId-227").length)` if this returns 1, then it means you have the object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146763/on-click-svg-image-path-get-path-id

Comment: try `document.querySelector('#uniqueDomId-227')`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On click svg image path get path id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146763/on-click-svg-image-path-get-path-id)

Comment: Perhaps the id is being assigned after your running the code to select it. You can run a `setInterval` and check what @CarstenLøvboAndersen proposed until you get 1. Then cancel the interval and you can use GSAP's own selector code: `TweenLite.to("#uniqueDomId-227", 1, {})`