# How can I save my generated svg code to a .svg file in the client machine?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I used snap.svg library to generate, with javascript, a svg element in my asp.net web form page by loading other external .svg files and manipulating them in order to get the final svg element. Once the composition of the desired svg object is finish and the resulting svg element shows fine in my page, I need to save it as an .svg file in the client machine, in a user selected path. Any idea about how to do it directly? I mean, whithout sending the code to the server, generate the file in the server, and then download the file to the client machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in two simple steps:

1. Use `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);` to get a String from your SVG
2. Use FileSaver.js to actually save the file (https://github.com/koffsyrup/FileSaver.js)

This should work in most cases (except Safari, of course).

Comment: It is very difficult / impossible to save files locally with Javascript on Safari. You can find a huge discussion thread on this subject at https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/12

Comment: ok, actually just a link with the dataUrl and a notice to right-click, "save the file as..." will do the trick for browsers which don't support `download` attribute.

Comment: I have tried it, but what I get is "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'serializeToString' on 'XMLSerializer': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'."

Comment: @AnastasiosOikonomidis  Then your svg parameter is not an SVG node. Try "console.log(typeof  svg)) before you call the XMLSerializer to see what you are actually passing to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed inline SVG code in the data URI of an `img` element:

```html
<img src='data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
</svg>' />
```

Saving is not initiated automatically, but the user can right-click → Save image as. The SVG needs to have `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`, like in an SVG file. To embed an existing SVG element, take its `outerHTML` and create the `img` element with that HTML in the data URI, as seen above.

Caveats:

- When saving, the default file name suggested by the browser will be something like `download.svg`, and I don't think you can change that.
- Single quotes (`'`) cannot be used in the SVG, because they are used to denote where the data URI starts and ends.
- You [cannot modify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46516718/4770915) the contents of the SVG afterwards, because it is in an `img` tag.
- The SVG will not use the styles of the page, but you would have that problem with the saved SVG file using any other approach, too.