# Can't access SVG contents with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg, dom

I have an SVG image on the HTML page. The image is loaded fine and is visible on the screen. I try to access it with js, but no luck. The mimimal example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <button onclick="print();">Print</button>
        <object data="drawing.svg" type="image/svg+xml" onload="print();"></object>
    </body>

    <script>
        function print() {
            var obj = document.body.getElementsByTagName("object")[0];
            console.log("obj = " + obj);
            console.log("obj.getSVGDocument() = " + obj.getSVGDocument());
            console.log("obj.contentDocument = " + obj.contentDocument);
            console.log("obj.firstElementChild = " + obj.firstElementChild);
            console.log("obj.childNodes.length = " + obj.childNodes.length);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Try to access it right after it was loaded or later on a button click, the console output is always:

```
obj = [object HTMLObjectElement]
obj.getSVGDocument() = null
obj.contentDocument = null
obj.firstElementChild = null
obj.childNodes.length = 0
```

I also checked the famous [snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3379830/1453413), but it gave me

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementById' of null at HTMLObjectElement.<anonymous>
```

Tested in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox. Am I missing something? The SVG is seen in the DOM with all its contents and elements. Why are they inaccessible then?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by placing the files on the Internet (previously they were offline).

After putting them online, I could reach `contentDocument`, it was no longer null. Console output:

```xml
obj.contentDocument = [object XMLDocument]
```

Then I could alter the contents of SVG with javascript...